# How can I upload file with special word?

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces, jboss

I have a simple code  File Upload in java and it works fine.

The problem is when I upload a file name with accent (like : é à ...) it doesn't work

**Java code**

```
public void upload() {  
    if(file != null) {  
        System.out.println(file.getFileName());
    }  
}
```

**XHTML code**

```xml
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">  
    <p:messages showDetail="true"/>  
    <p:fileUpload value="#{fileUploadController.file}" mode="simple"/>  
    <p:commandButton value="Submit" ajax="false"  
            actionListener="#{fileUploadController.upload}"/>  
</h:form>
```

**Result:**

```
INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2)   C:\Users\test\dÃ©tail 0120.xlsx
```

Comment: It means you are sending the filename in UTF-8, but your container is configured to read ISO-8859-1.

Comment: set char set to unicode. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/unicode.html